# Overflow when processing historical price data (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, stack-overflow, large-data

I'm writing a macro that reads price data from an excel file, write them on another excel file and does basic calculations (e.g. returns). The data is made of 2600 x 100 data points.

When I run it i have an overflow error! looks like it's handling too much data. Is it an issue with the computer's memory? (i have a modern laptop with 4GB Ram) or does it have to do with the way the data is stored during the calulations? What I don't get is that if I try to do that kind of calculations in the spreadsheet directly, i won't have an overflow message.

Btw, I'm trying to avoid using Access.

Thanks for your help.

Sam
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim m As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Dim o As Long

' FYI yearsconsidered = 10

```
For j = 1 To Group(k).TickerCount
    For m = 1 To Quotes(j, k).ContinuationCount
        For i = 1 To YearsConsidered * 261
            If Sheets(j).Cells(i - GivenPeriod, 4 * m - 3) = 0 Then
                Sheets(j).Cells(i, 4 * m - 2) = 0
            Else
                Sheets(j).Cells(i, 4 * m - 2) = (Sheets(j).Cells(i, 4 * m - 3) - Sheets(j).Cells(i - GivenPeriod, 4 * m - 3)) / Sheets(j).Cells(i - GivenPeriod, 4 * m - 3)
            End If
        Next i
    Next m
Next j
```

Comment: Try posting some code.

Comment: For j = 1 To Group(k).TickerCount
        For m = 1 To Quotes(j, k).ContinuationCount
            For i = 1 To YearsConsidered * 261
                If Sheets(j).Cells(i - GivenPeriod, 4 * m - 3) = 0 Then
                    Sheets(j).Cells(i, 4 * m - 2) = 0
                Else
                    Sheets(j).Cells(i, 4 * m - 2) = (Sheets(j).Cells(i, 4 * m - 3) - Sheets(j).Cells(i - GivenPeriod, 4 * m - 3)) / Sheets(j).Cells(i - GivenPeriod, 4 * m - 3)
                End If
            Next i
        Next m
    Next j

Comment: cannot keep my nice formatting...

Comment: I guess I should have been more specific. Please put the code **in the question** and include the variable declarations and indicate where the error occurs. If `i` is declared as `Integer` change it to `Long`.

Comment: THx Rory.  Done.  I declared all my looping variables as long instead of integer: instead of performing 60% of the calculations before crashing it only does 10%.

Comment: You didn't indicate where the error occurs.

Comment: Also now cross-posted here: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/871077-visual-basic-applications-overflow-price-data-acquisition.html

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced a similar situation when I'm looping through a large number of data points.  For some reason, this does not happen if I code the formula entry into a range of cells (at the same time); like when you manually select a range in the spreadsheet, enter the formula once, then hit Ctrl+Enter.  This will require for the proper use of the $ signs (absolute vs relational positions).
It's hard to tell exactly what the issue is without seeing the code, so not sure if this is your problem...

Comment: Thx. I am not sure i understand what your solution is.

Comment: The macro is reading the prices cell by cell (performs checks) and copies it to another spreadsheet. This part is ok. When I start calculating returns using these prices, I have the overflow error. Instead of putting the results into a spreadsheet I first tried to use user-defined data types to stock the values but I had an overflow issue.